# Return values from asynchronous function

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I'm trying to use my first Asynchronous function is VB.NET, and I get an error I don't understand.

I have read in the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/mt674902.aspx) that

'  - The return type is Task or Task(Of T). (See "Return Types" section.)

'    Here, it is Task(Of Integer) because the return statement returns an integer.

Here is the (very simple) code.

```
Async Sub Main()
    Dim test
    test = Await funcAsync()
End Sub

Function funcAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
    Dim result As Integer
    result = 2
    funcAsync = result
End Function
```

I have a compile error in the `funcAsync = result` line: Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'Task(Of Integer)'

I can't figure out what I did wrong here.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use 'Return result' instead of funcAsync = result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use Await on functions declared with the "Async" keyword. And the "Async" keyword can't be used on a Sub.

If your code is for a Console Application, you need to put all your async processing inside of a function and on Sub Main you should call the Wait() method on the object returned by that function. Here is a code that works for me:

```
Sub Main()
    DoProcessing().Wait()
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

Async Function DoProcessing() As Task
    Dim test = Await funcAsync()
    Console.WriteLine(test)
End Sub

Async Function funcAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
    Dim result = 2
    Return result
End Function
```